# How to compare preg_match_all case-insensitive arrays

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match-all

I've used `array_udiff()` to compare case-insensitive arrays, this works fine with the code below i.e. the word `"flower"` is found in both arrays whether it's lower or in uppercase.

```
$array1 = array("sun", "World", "FLOWER");
$array2 = array("you", "your", "flower");

$result = array_udiff($array1, $array2, 'strcasecmp');

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => sun [1] => World )
```

Now I've been trying to use `array_udiff()` with `preg_match_all()`. First see an example below with `array_diff()`. The first `preg_match_all()` is looking for a match between the array `$findWords` and `$text1`. The second `preg_match_all()` is then looking for a match between the output of the first `preg_match_all()` and `$text2`.

```
$text1 = "Hello WORLD";
$findWord = array('WORLD', 'you');

// First preg_match
foreach ($findWord as $findWords1) {
    if (preg_match_all("~\b$findWords1\b~i", $text1, $matchWords1)) {  
        $matchWords1 = $matchWords1[0];
    }  

    $text2 = "Hello world";

    // Second preg_match
    foreach ($matchWords1 as $findWords2)  
        if (preg_match_all("~\b$findWords2\b~i", $text2, $matchWords2)) {
            $matchWords2 = $matchWords2[0];
        }    

    $result = array_diff($matchWords1, $matchWords2);
    $match = array_unique($result);

    foreach ($match as $matches) 
        echo $matches.'<br>';  
}
```

Output:

```
WORLD
```

So here is my problem, I'd like to be able to compare the two arrays `$matchWords1` and `$matchWords2`, so if "world" is in lowercase in `$text2`, it's still a match to "WORLD". Note I want to keep the uppercase / lowercase words from `$findWords`, so I'm not looking for a `strtolower()` solution.

Here is my attempts with `array_udiff()` and `strcasecmp()`, but it returns an empty array:

```
$text1 = "Hello WORLD";
$findWord = array('WORLD', 'you');

// First preg_match
foreach ($findWord as $findWords1) {
    if (preg_match_all("~\b$findWords1\b~i", $text1, $matchWords1)) {  
        $matchWords1 = $matchWords1[0];
    }  

    $text2 = "Hello world";

    // Second preg_match
    foreach ($matchWords1 as $findWords2)  
        if (preg_match_all("~\b$findWords2\b~i", $text2, $matchWords2)) {
            $matchWords2 = $matchWords2[0];
        }    

    $result = array_udiff($matchWords1, $matchWords2, 'strcasecmp');
    $match = array_unique($result);

    echo "<pre>"; 
    print_r($match); 
    echo "</pre>";  
}
```

Output:

```
Array ( ) Array ( )
```

**EDIT:**

The output for the code below is the word "**WORLD**", but I'd like to make this code case insensitive so there is no output. For example if you change "world" in $text2 to UPPERCASE, there won't be any output, and that's what I want to achieve but with the word "world" in lowercase in $text2. Because "WORLD" and "world" are the same word.

```
$text1 = "Hello WORLD";

    $findWord = array('WORLD', 'you');

    // First preg_match
    foreach ($findWord as $findWords1)            {

    if (preg_match_all("~\b$findWords1\b~i", $text1, $matchWords1)) {  

    $matchWords1 = $matchWords1[0];

    }  

    $text2 = "Hello world";

    // Second preg_match
    foreach ($matchWords1 as $findWords2)  

    if (preg_match_all("~\b$findWords2\b~i", $text2, $matchWords2))  {

        $matchWords2 = $matchWords2[0];

    }    

    $result = array_diff($matchWords1, $matchWords2);
    $match = array_unique($result);

    foreach ($match as $matches) 

    echo $matches.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Too much going on, just show the input, what the output should be and WHY the output should be that.

Comment: Make the question more specific.It should be like this: **Input - Output - preferred output - the code which you have a problem with it**. Simple but useful :)

Comment: Please see [mcve], and focus on the _clear problem statement_ (and "minimal") aspects.

Comment: `array_udiff()` returns the words that are *not* in both arrays. But you want to find the words that *are* in both arrays, the exact opposite.

Comment: Use `array_uintersect()` for that.

Answer (score 0):

`array_udiff` returns elements of first array that are not present in the second one. You need to use `array_uintersect` if you want the opposite. Just change the line:

```
$result = array_udiff($matchWords1, $matchWords2, 'strcasecmp');
```

to:

```
$result = array_uintersect($matchWords1, $matchWords2, 'strcasecmp');
```

and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But array_uintersect still returns "WORLD". There shouldn't be any output if the word "world" is in $findWord as well as in $text1 and $text2. If you put the word "world" in uppercase in $text2, there aren't any output, and that's what I'd like but case insensitive.